# How to properly use TryGetValue Method with a class as Key?

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, generics, initialization

My question is relative to the use of a dictionary. I will try to attach the code and then to explain my doubt:

```
    var ambassadors = new Dictionary<CountryCode, Ambassador>();
    Ambassador england = new Ambassador
    {
        CountryCode = new CountryCode("eng"),
        Name = "John",
        Age = 25

    };
    Ambassador australia = new Ambassador
    {
        CountryCode = new CountryCode("aus"),
        Name = "Martin",
        Age = 49

    };

    ambassadors.Add(england.CountryCode, england);
    ambassadors.Add(australia.CountryCode, australia);


    Console.WriteLine("Enter country code: ");
    var code = Console.ReadLine();

    if (ambassadors.TryGetValue(new CountryCode(code), out Ambassador ambassador))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The ambassador is {ambassador.Name}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The ambassador with the given code does not exist in the dictonary");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Ambassador
{
    public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class CountryCode
{
    public string Code { get; }

    public CountryCode(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;

        }
        if (!(obj is CountryCode))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(this.Code, ((CountryCode)obj).Code);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(this.Code);
    }
```

My doubt is related to the line where I use the

```
ambassadors.TryGetValue
```

method inside the if to check the key and give me back the value.
My question is: Why should I create a new instance (or initialize) of the Class CountrySide inside the TryGetValue?
I mean an instance of the class already exist inside ambassadors Dictionary. So, why c# ask me to initialize a new one inside the TryGetValue method and not simply check if that one specific exist, without the "new" before CoutryCode(code)?
If you could clarify me this concept I would appreciate it really.

Comment: You have created a dictionary in which the keys are all _CountryCode_ instances. Therefore, to search for an instance of CountryCode, the method needs a variable of type CountryCode. (And a set of methods appropriate for recognizing the exact CountryCode instance from those present in its keys.) If you were using a string as a key, you would have had to pass a string. But CountryCode is a class and a class needs _new_ to instantiate

Comment: *"and not simply check if that one specific exist"* -- How does the C# know what is the specific `CountryCode` that you are searching for, without you providing one?

Comment: Hello @Steve ! Thanks a lot for the prompt respond! Mmh.. ok, i understand that a class always need to be instantiated in order to use it! But why in here since that inside this dictonary is it is already implied that the key is a cass CountryCode and all i want is checking if the one im giving with the Console.readline() exist or not? I don't see the meaning of create a new instance here but maybe i am wrong.. I don't know if i you explaining it my doubt well, sorry!

Comment: Hello @TheodorZoulias! Thanks for the reply. Well what i mean is that i will provide it with the Console.ReadLine() and then checking if exist! But i don't understand the necessity to create a new instance inside the TryGetValue method..

Comment: So you want the C# compiler to produce an executable based on your intentions, and not on the actual code that you write?

Comment: @Theodir Zoulias Of course not! This is why i am asking! Because i want to understand what it is not clear to me!

Comment: @Theodir Zoulias I would write the code like this "if (ambassadors.TryGetValue(CountryCode(code), out Ambassador ambassador))" because i don't see the meaning to use "new" here. I understand that class need to be instantiated but not see the necessity in here since the class is already instantiated! Probabily it's easy to understand, i will try to think a little bit more about it!

Comment: The expression `CountryCode(code)` implies that the `CountryCode` is a method with a return value. What would be the return value of this method, if not a newly created `CountryCode` instance? If you want to cache and reuse a `CountryCode` instance, you must do it yourself. You must have a pool of `CountryCode` instances somewhere, and manage this pool manually. The C# doesn't have enough information to create such a pool automatically. The .NET is very efficient at managing memory though, so creating a few "superfluous" `CountryCode` instances is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need CountryCode class, string type would be plenty

```
var ambassadors = new Dictionary<string, Ambassador>();

public class Ambassador
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
....
Ambassador england = new Ambassador
    {
        CountryCode = "eng",
        Name = "John",
        Age = 25

    };

if (  ambassadors.TryGetValue(code, out var ambassador))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The ambassador is {ambassador.Name}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The ambassador with the given code \"{code}\" does not exist in the dictonary");
    }

// or you can use this too

if (ambassadors.ContainsKey(code)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The ambassador is {ambassadors[code].Name}");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"The ambassador with the given code \"{code}\" does not exist in the dictonary");
    }
```

if for some reasons you need CountryCode class, IMHO it is better to define a dictionary this way. In this case you probably don' t need a  bool Equals(object obj) method of CountryCode class.

```
var ambassadors = new Dictionary<string, Ambassador>();
```

you can add item to dictionary this way

```
    Ambassador england = new Ambassador
    {
        CountryCode = new CountryCode("eng"),
        Name = "John",
        Age = 25

    };
    Ambassador australia = new Ambassador
    {
        CountryCode = new CountryCode("aus"),
        Name = "Martin",
        Age = 49

    };

    ambassadors.Add(england.CountryCode.Code, england);
    ambassadors.Add(australia.CountryCode.Code, australia);
```

all another code will be the same as I posted above

Comment: Hello @Serge thanks for reply me and for showing me a new perspective! The reason of why i am using a class instead is just because the exercise require it! Probabily because to show after that how to override the Equals and GetHashCode method! I know it's  little bit twisted but this is why!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and comments already elaborated on it: Your dictionary is keyed by `CountryCode` and therefore needs a `CountryCode` instance, hence the requirement for `new` in

```cs
ambassadors.TryGetValue(new CountryCode(code), out var ambassador)
```

I would like to comment on a different angle here: While you can make the dictionary keyed by `string` and then use

```cs
var ambassadors = new Dictionary<string, Ambassador>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
// ...
ambassadors.TryGetValue(code, out var ambassador)
```

directly, it needs to leak knowledge about how country codes are compared - note the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in there.

I believe there may be a benefit in changing `CountryCode` to a `struct` instead:

```cs
public readonly struct CountryCode
{
    public string Code { get; }
    // ...
}
```

This will keep all validation code in place - i.e., the type constructor can still check whether something is a valid country code, not null or whitespace, etc. - but it will save resources on the allocation: Since a `struct` is a value type, `new` allocates on the stack rather than on the heap and is therefore virtually free as far as your usage here is concerned.

The crucial part - and you already have that - is to have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` set up. As mentioned above, the `Equals` is important here as it allows to treat treats both `eng` and `ENG` as similar. Given that, any type keyed by a `CountryCode` does not need to know or care about the details of equating two country codes, which is a strong benefit over a `string` key.

For usability, I would recommend to also implement the `IEquatable<CountryCode>` interface, as well as the `operator ==` and `operator !=` overloads:

```cs
public readonly struct CountryCode : IEquatable<CountryCode>
{
    // Note: `default(CountryCode)` will not call the constructor!
    private readonly string? _code;
    
    public CountryCode(string code)
    {
        // Verify country codes, throw exceptions, ...
        _code = code?.Trim().ToLowerInvariant() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(code));
    }

    // Note: ensure proper values for `default(CountryCode)`.
    public string Code => _code ?? string.Empty; 

    public bool Equals(CountryCode other) =>
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Code, other);

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) =>
        obj is CountryCode other && Equals(other);

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Code);

    public static bool operator ==(CountryCode lhs, CountryCode rhs) => 
        lhs.Equals(rhs);

    public static bool operator !=(CountryCode lhs, CountryCode rhs) => 
        !lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

If you're dealing with with common names, I had some successes with making the constructor private and naming out the values like so:

```cs
public readonly struct CountryCode : IEquatable<CountryCode>
{
    public static readonly CountryCode Empty = default;
    public static readonly CountryCode England = new("eng");
    public static readonly CountryCode Australia = new("aus");

    // ...
}
```

Most deserialization code would still pick up the private constructor, but any application code would be forced to use allowed values. This may or may not be useful for your case.

Note that could also use a `string` conversion operator like this:

```
public static implicit operator string(CountryCode code) =>
    code.Code;
```

Being explicit (`var code = countryCode.Code`) is usually better than being implicit (`var code = countryCode`) though, so take it with a grain of salt.

So my recommendation here is:

- stick with the `CountryCode` key,
- make `CountryCode` a `readonly struct` instead of a `class`, this makes it better and faster
- keep an eye out for `default(CountryCode)` instances, as they will not have the constructor called; in `class` types, the entire value would be `null` then.

Comment: Hello @sunside ! Wow! Thanks a lot for the tips!! Yes the reason of why i am doing with the class CountryCode and not with string type it's because after i need to demonstrate how to override those methods! But thanks a lot for the tips about the struct! Even if i don't use structs a lot i and therefore if am not very familiar with them, i know more or less what they are and i completly understand what you mean! Yes in this case this would optimize the code, very interesting! Thanks :)!